# Delete folder on server by FTP Connection

Tags: objective-c, ios, ftp

I am learning about networking with iOS.

How can I delete a folder on a remote server that I have connected through via FTP?

I tried use CFURLDestroyResource function but it failed. It only deletes files.

I have tried this code :

```
NSURL * url;
SInt32 status = 0;
url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"ftp://sikmac3:remuz@localhost/TestFolder"];
CFURLRef urlRef; 
urlRef = (CFURLRef) url;

Boolean test = CFURLDestroyResource(urlRef, &status);
if(test){ NSLog(@"deletion success"); }else{ NSLog(@"deletion failed"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.

Try with this:

```
url= [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"ftp://sikmac3:remuz@localhost/TestFolder/"];
                                                                             ^
```

File and folder is a almost same, but add a `/` at the end of folders.
That's all.